# Could Not Connect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localhost

[image]When I try to run my project as it gives an error:

> Could Not Connect
>   Description: Could not connect to the requested server host.

I tried a few things but it doesn't work.
I checked my antivirus program,my localhost and VS2015.
My project ASP.Net Mvc by the way.
Any idea can help me.Thanks a lot!

Comment: what says the debugger console in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your project to another browser.
ex(Mozilla)

or

you can check the browser setting.
For Chrome: goto chrome://settings/ -> advanced setting -> change proxy settings -> connections -> lan settings

> Uncheck proxy server

Comment: I fixed Uncheck proxy server. thanks a lot rjay dadula.